# How to read formatted cell value data using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, cell, formatted

What I'm trying to is read formatted cell value in excel 2007 using VBA.

For example I have a cell with value **"01/01/2015"** and when formatted it looks like **Jan/2015**.
Is there a way to read that formatted value **Jan/2015** into a variable instead of "01/01/2015"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
someVariable = Range("A1").Text
```

instead

```
someVariable = Range("A1").Value
```

you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217%28v=office.15%29.aspx)