# How to get a cell with format as Date in another Locale

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a cell, `M1`, whose format is set as Date with Locale as **Persian**. But the problem is when I read the cell value through this VBA command `Range("M1").value`, I still get the usual English calendar(Gregorian calendar) as output. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: A date value in excel is just a number - what you see in the cell is just formatting.  What do you need to do with the value you read from M1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995255/how-to-read-formatted-cell-value-data-using-excel-vba) explains it. Use `Range.Text` instead of `Range.Value` property.

Comment: If you think that the linked post answers the question, you should mark the question as duplicate. Anyhow, `Range.Text` has it's problems: If a cell is hidden, you get an empty string as result. If a cell is too narrow and therefore you see "####", `Range.Text` will return "####"

Comment: @FunThomas those are some bad drawbacks but sometimes you just want to get what is displayed, I wrangled with this problem for about 2 days before finding this answer.